# SQL query in dire need of optimization

Tags: sql, pervasive

I have this query, which works fine, except it takes a couple of minutes to load. I need help optimizing it so it runs faster and I don't know where to start:

```
SELECT 
    job_header.job,
    job_header.suffix,
    job_header.customer,
    job_header.description,
    job_header.comments_1,
    job_header.date_due,
    job_header.part,
    job_header.customer_po,
    job_header.date_closed,
    job_header.flag_hold,
    job_header.code_sort,
    wo_user_flds.user_7,
    wo_user_flds.user_3,
    wo_user_flds.user_6,
    wo_user_flds.user_5,
    wo_user_flds.user_2,
    quote_lines.user_2 as serialNo,
    quote_lines.user_3 as unit,
    quote_lines.user_4 as package

FROM job_header

LEFT JOIN wo_user_flds ON 
    (job_header.job = wo_user_flds.job) AND
    (job_header.suffix = wo_user_flds.suffix)

LEFT JOIN quote_lines ON
    (job_header.part = quote_lines.part)

WHERE job_header.date_closed = '000000'

AND LENGTH(job_header.job) > 5;
```

More information that might be of use:

- Only the columns found in the select are the columns I need.
- My query returns roughly 400 records.
- Job_Header table has 97 columns and 6,300 records.
- Wo_User_Flds table has 12 columns and 1,100 records.
- Quote_Lines table has 198 columns and 46,000 records.

I could speculate on what I think I need to do, but I'm really just guessing at this point. I looked at similar questions and lot of talk of 'indexes', so I checked and these tables do have some indexes...if that helps? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

Thanks for the quick responses guys, really appreciate it. I'm going to look into everything everyone said, but here is the ddl for these tables: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247664/

[EDIT 2]

My query takes 1 minute to load. My expectations may not be realistic in how much faster it can be. I might have to resort to breaking up the query into more than one and then just assemble the data on the client.

Comment: Without more information, we'd be guessing too. Can you post an EXPLAIN, and the DDL?

Comment: Do you have an index on the `date_closed` column?  How selective is `000000` (meaning how many rows does that condition match out of the overall table)?

Comment: are there indexes on wo_user_flds(job, suffix) and job_header(job, Suffix) and job_header(part) and Quote_Lines(part) and Job_header(date_Closed) and is that really a string? and have you considered a function based index on job_header(job) for length?  in Job Header How many records vary in lengths?

Comment: @NevilleK It looks like this database (Pervasive) does not support the `explain` command, but here is your ddl: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247664/

Comment: @Brandon I do not have an index on `date_closed`. My query returns roughly 400 records, so a lot less than what's in these tables. I thought maybe I need to add more conditionals, but I don't know if that's really optimization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could use a function-based index on `LENGTH(job_header.job)`.  Have a look at that.

Comment: @xQbert Indexes on all of those, except `quote_lines.part` and `job_header.date_closed`. Yes, the date is really a string type. I don't know what you mean by a new function? I thought that's what the `length()` was? And not sure what you mean by vary in length.

Comment: @Marc So you're echoing what the other guy said, about the function-based index. I will look into this then, thank you.

Comment: I've looked at Google, but can find no answer - does Pervasive support using more than a single index in a query? Also, it doesn't appear there's an index on date_closed.

Answer (score 4):

Without any other info you'd need an index on job_header on either (job, date_closed) or (date_closed, job). But post the indexes on the table e.g. sp_helpindex or better still the create index script (right click on the index in SSMS and script the index)

Comment: Plus one because person does not have enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: I've updated my original post to show the DDL, where you'll see my available indexes. `date_closed` is not one of them unfortunately.

Comment: An index on `job` may not be usable due to the function call.  If the DBMS supports a function index, that would be great.  One could add a computed column to persist the length and index that, but the cost may outweigh the benefit if the other column is already selective enough.

Comment: Yer - just realised it wasn't MS SQL Server; I didn't see the LENGTH either - but, indexing Job in SQL Server would only benefit by giving you an index scan; you are probably better doing something like Job > '000000' or something like that (if you know the data!)

Comment: OK so it looks possible to add an index to a table, but I'm not sure if I want to go that route because I'm afraid of breaking something for I don't understand index and all the caveats to it. But if I were to add an index to every column I'm using, would that drastically improve anything? My problems see to be lack of index and my usage of `length`.

Comment: I don't know your data, but it might be possible to remove the LENGTH thing entirely - what value does SELECT MIN( job ) FROM job_header WHERE LENGTH( job ) > 5 return? That should give you your base value for where the length of job because greater than 5 - you could then use that value in your where clause meaning the index on job would be used. Try that - compare with the LENGTH and with the > 'your base 5 character value'

Comment: I see what you're saying, use the actual value in the row instead of trying to calculate every single one by character length. I went from `LENGTH(job_header.job) > 5` to `job_header.job > 015281`, but unfortunately the speed was almost the same. It takes a minute. I'm not sure if I have realistic expectations. Maybe it's supposed to take this long and it can't be sped up? I can't have the user waiting for data to load, so maybe I come up with some other tricks.

Answer (score 3):

First be sure you have indexes on columns where you JOIN tables and your "WHERE clause column". In this case, you should have indexes on these columns:

```
--Table job_header indexes, beside unique index
job_header.job
job_header.suffix
job_header.part = quote_lines.part
job_header.date_closed

--Table wo_users_flds indexes, beside unique index
wo_user_flds.job
wo_user_flds.suffix
```

Then, avoid using UDFs (functions, like LENGHT, CAST, concatenation etc.). But in this case, you can leave LENGTH there. So your query would be same, only your indexes would improve query execution plan drastically.

Also, use execution plan to see where you have INDEX_SCAN and INDEX_SEEK. If you have INDEX_SCAN somewhere, it should be sign that you need index on that column.

This would be for start.

Comment: I have indexes on some of those columns, but not all of them, i.e. `date_closed` and `part`. I'm not sure if you can add indexes after table creation? I will look into that. Also, I didn't realize those were considered user defined functions, interesting. I've never heard of an execution plan so I will investigate, thank you.

Comment: They are not user defined functions.  They are native functions but the effect is the same.  If you use them to filter data, you slow down production.